# ajax form submit without refresh error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form in `AJAX` working, but when i have more than one form on the same page appears an error.

```
    <script>
  var fmx = jQuery.noConflict();
    fmx(document).ready(function(){
    fmx('form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      fmx.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'https://www.webshop.com/post.php',
        data: fmx('form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
           document.getElementById('#form_post').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('#form_result').style.display = '';
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="#form_post" style="display:inherit">
<form class="form_post">
    <label for="post_email">FORM</label>
    <input id="post_email" class="post_email" type="email" name="post_email" placeholder="your@email.com" required>
    <input id="post_data" class="post_data" type="text" name="post_data" placeholder="MSG" required>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="POST" >
</form>
</div>
<div id="#form_result" style="display:none"><br>Success.</div>
```

I tried to switch to a #id but it stopped working.

```
    <script>
  var fmx = jQuery.noConflict();
    fmx(document).ready(function(){
    fmx('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      fmx.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'https://www.webshop.com/post.php',
        data: fmx('#form').serialize(),
        success: function () {
           document.getElementById('#form_post').style.display = 'none';
           document.getElementById('#form_result').style.display = '';
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
<form class="form_post" id="form">
```

How do put an `ID` on this form?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: IDs must be unique.

Comment: The HTML supplement does not have an ID on the form either

Comment: That statement refers to element IDs which indeed _must_ be unique throughout a page.

Comment: And an element ID should be specified without a `#` in the `id="..."` element property.

Comment: 1. give the same class to all forms like `<form class="form_post">`.2 `fmx('.form_post').on('submit', function (e) {`.3. `data: fmx(this).serialize(),`

Comment: @SLaks In the first example, when sending another form from page, only the form in Ajax is sent. In the second example, its not sent.

Comment: @Anant thank you, its work for me :)

Comment: @user4817258  since you are not responding I am deleting my answer. I posted it because you said that my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The first method would implement the listener on all forms found on page.

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){

    // All forms targeted

})
```

The second method is probably not working because there is an ID conflict on the page.

ID's are unique and can only be used once in HTML. The second code block is correctly targeting the html you want and the code is looking for a form with an ID of "#form".

This form does exist and the ID is indeed #form so thas stated there must be a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fmx = jQuery.noConflict();
fmx(document).ready(function() {
  fmx('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
    fmx.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'https://www.webshop.com/post.php',
      data: fmx(form).serialize(),
      success: function() {
        form.style.display = 'none';
        form.style.display = '';
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This may be able to work with multiple forms on the page, by manipulating the form that was submitted using `this` that we're setting to `form`.

As everyone has stated, you can't use an ID more than once in the HTML, or otherwise it isn't uniquely identifying the element it tags. So if you want to target two or more occurrences of something you need to use a class instead.

If you are able to wrap your head around the fact that you have access to the DOM object (via `this`) that triggered the event (in this case one of your forms being submitted), you can make use of it in the script.

Bear in mind that as you change scopes, (like in the `success` callback function) `this` is going to be a reference to something else. So you need to assign it like we did with `var form = this;` the moment the form is submitted.